# Upload files to a public skydrive link

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8, onedrive

I see that the SkyDrive API provides methods for uploading files from an application to the SkyDrive account of an authenticated user. What I would like to do is to upload a file from my application to a SkyDrive folder, for which I have only the edit link and no user information. However, I can not find any method providing this in the SkyDrive API.

Am I missing anything in the SkyDrive API? Is something like this achievable through a different approach?

Comment: well, you can create folder on a users account but, authentication is a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible.

If you are going to put files in a Skydrive account, you need to authenticate yourself -- either as the owner of the account, or as a user who has full access rights to the folder.

Here are the Guidelines for Accessing SkyDrive from an App: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263258.aspx

Comment: ok, so, the user owning the folder must specifically share it with the user who wants to add files to it?

Comment: I don't think so. Check out the API documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521.aspx